# How do I make a div appear in the center of a dynamically created table row?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a `div` inside a table row, and the catch is that it should be in the center of that row. This is my code:

```
table.rows[0].cells.item(0).innerHTML = "<b>Confirm all</b>";
var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
inp.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
table.rows[0].cells.item(1).appendChild(inp);
var row = table.insertRow(1);
row.style.padding="5px";
var span = document.createElement("div");
span.style.width="100%";
span.style.textAlign="center";
span.style.verticalAlign="center";
span.style.lineHeight="50px";
span.innerText = "OR";
row.appendChild(span);
```

This is the output that I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1E1v.png)

As you can see in the image, the div is always there in the left side of the row, I want it to be in the center. How do I do that?

Comment: can you share your html, css and JS in a snippet please ?

Comment: without your html, css, little hard! I would say you are putting span texAlign center, but you also put it at 100%, so it's already full width. Try without the 100%, or you'll have to put a div to 100% textAlign center, and a span inside the div with "OR"

Comment: @pier farrugia I am creating the rows `dynamically`

Comment: You can right click and inspect the elements to see what HTML has been output by your code, you can then copy that into your question to help (in chrome you can literally right click the parent node and then copy, paste here)

Comment: yes I've seen that. When you're creating your div to put the OR, it's 100% and textAlign center. Try just to change span.innerText from "OR" to "<span>OR</span>"

Comment: What you are doing is fine, but you are inserting the element into a single table cell, if you want that cell to cover the entire width, you will need to use the `colSpan` property ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost works. To make the text in the center of your table row, you just put your span/div element inside `td` element. Try to replace this:

```
row.appendChild(span);
```

with this

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.colSpan = "2";
td.appendChild(span);
row.appendChild(td);
```

---

Don't forget to add colspan attribute in the `td` element. Full code:

```js
document.getElementById("rep_tab").rows[3].cells.item(0).innerHTML = "<b>Confirm all</b>";
var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
inp.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
document.getElementById("rep_tab").rows[3].cells.item(1).appendChild(inp);
var row = document.getElementById("rep_tab").insertRow(4);
row.style.padding="5px";
var span = document.createElement("div");
span.style.width="100%";
span.style.textAlign="center";
span.style.verticalAlign="center";
span.style.lineHeight="50px";
span.innerText = "OR";

// new code
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.colSpan = "2";
td.appendChild(span);
row.appendChild(td);
```

```html
<table id="rep_tab" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```